# Why should fseek be called with offset of -2 instead an offset of -1 in the program that prints the text file backwards?

Tags: c, file, text, fseek

The following C program prints a text file backwards:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEEK_SET 0
#define SEEK_CUR 1
#define SEEK_END 2
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp = f
   open(argv[1], "r");
   fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_END);
   while (ftell(fp)) 
   {
      putchar(fgetc(fp));
       fseek(fp, -2L, SEEK_CUR);
   }

putchar(fgetc(fp));
```

Since the program is supposed to print the text file backwards, it is supposed to read each and every character from the end, without skipping any characters. If so,I thought the call within the while loop should be

```
fseek(fp, -1L, SEEK_CUR);
```

How come the offset is -2 and not -1?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fgetc() moved it forward by 1, so you have to move back 2 to get to the char before it.

Comment: Because a seek of -1 would show you the same character each time.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to be portable - text files cannot be "sought" arbitrarily

Comment: Thank you very much. I still don't understand, when I get a character using fgetc, I want to go 1 place backwards from the very character I've just got with fgetc, so why is the offset -2? @Hans Passant

Comment: @Tree  Because you don't want to go back to the very character you just got.  You want to go back to the one before that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't get it, suppose getc returned 'd' and the character before that was 'c'. Then I'd need to go backwards 1 step from d, not 2. What's my mistake?
 @William Pursell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call fgetc, offset goes 1 char ahead of what you expect, so you need to move 2 back to get the char you expect to get. Otherwise you would be getting the same char all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much. fgetc goes 1 char ahead only after it returned the character, right? @Luis Cabrero

Comment: If fgetc doesnt succeed, it returns EOF (end of file) and it sets errno to indicate the error. So, yes, it goes 1 char ahead only if a char is returned. If you go backwards this isnt going to happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, I'm still not sure about something: suppose my text file contains the string "abcd", then fgetc will return 'd' and then advance the indicator to the right by 1 position, and there is nothing in there.Then it will go backwards 2 positions by calling fssek, so the character would be 'c'. Then fgetc will advance the indicator to 'd', and then the call to feek with an offset of -2 is made, so now the character 'b' is printed and so on.... am I right? @Luis Cabrero

Comment: First step: "abcd", if the offset is on the d, fgetc, would return 'd'. Then the offset would be on the EOF (end of file). After this, if you call fseek with -2L, you place the offset on the 'c', again, you call fgetc, it returns 'c'. This would continue executing this way. Notice that if you have "abcd" and the offset is on the d, if you call twice fgetc, you would force program to crash, because you cant call fgetc on EOF. I think you got it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind, clear and detailed explanation, and for your patience. You really helped me and I really appreciate it! 
 @Luis Cabrero